# How to prepare the data in this form using python

Tags: python, data-science

I have excel data file in following format

[image]

I want to prepare the data in the following format:
[image]

Can I do this using python?

Comment: please see [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/working-csv-files-python/) code snippet. once you get data in rows and fields list . iteration overs rows list to get the target format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are learning data science, I suggest you use [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/index.html), a very important library in the Python data science stack.
Pandas can read many file formats, including excel, and convert them into an internal format called `DataFrame`. You can then perform many operations on `DataFrame` objects, including statistics, plotting, and analyses.
The general technique that you are looking for is called unpivoting, and it is available in method [melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt) of a `DataFrame`.
Here is a code snippet, feel free to change it to suit your needs.

```py
import pandas as pd


df_orig = pd.read_excel("YOUR_FILE.xlsx")

attributes = ["color", "liquid"]
df_new = df_orig.melt(id_vars=attributes)
```

By the way, you should really ponder what of the original variables you want to include in `id_vars` argument of `melt`. Usually, only categorical variables are used for pivoting and unpivoting. So, in your example, I would use `color` and `liquid`, but I maybe would not use `size`, if it is a numerical variable. You can use `size` if it was a categorical ordinal variable.